# CUPS: HP printer DNS url

Tags: printing, hp, dns, dhcp

The URL for my printer generated by `hp-makeuri` looks like this:

```
hp:/net/Officejet_6500_E710n-z?ip=192.168.178.30
```

But the printer is on a dhcp enabled wifi network and so its IP-address does and could change. On the other hand my wifi router seems smart enough to have some sort of DNS:

```
$ ping hp-6500a
PING hp-6500a.fritz.box (192.168.178.30) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from hp-6500a.fritz.box (192.168.178.30): icmp_req=1 ttl=255 time=11.3 ms
```

I tried to use the hostname in the CUPS URL/DeviceUID but it failed, any suggestions if this is possible and the correct format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can make use of [ZeroConf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking) here to dynamically find your printer. The syntax is like:

```
hp:/net/Officejet_6500_E710n-z?zc=printer
```

There, `zc` stands for [ZeroConf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking), the [mDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) implemented by [avahi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_%28software%29).  On setting that URI, you may see some multicast network traffic to query the printer as can be seen in the partial tcpdump below.

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/avahi# tcpdump -vvvvvn -i wlan0 host 224.0.0.251
tcpdump: listening on wlan0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
11:20:49.783337 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 59)
    172.25.197.98.5353 > 224.0.0.251.5353: [udp sum ok] 0 A (QM)? printer.local. (31)
11:20:49.787975 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 44750, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 69)
    172.25.197.160.5353 > 224.0.0.251.5353: [udp sum ok] 0*- [0q] 1/0/0 printer.local. (Cache flush) [4m] A 172.25.197.160 (41)
```

DNS A records like `printer.anintranet.example` can be added to a dynamic zone by the DHCP server.  The original domain name (`anintranet.example`) is discarded -- possibly because it is in the "search" directive of `/etc/resolv.conf`?-- and `.local` is added as part of the mDNS query.